# Calculating average of specific values

Tags: excel, average

I want to find out the average cost of an apple, the price isn't always filled out, I know I should be able to do this with sumproduct, but it's not working for me.

```
  A       B
Fruit   Price
Apple   56
Banana  23
Apple   
Apple   40
Apple
```

My problem comes when I try to count how many apples have a price value entered.
Can anyone help?

**Note: I'm using Excel 2003 hence no countifs**

Comment: The online docs for Excel 2003 say that `countif` exists. Is that not correct?

Comment: ....but `COUNTIFS` [with an "S"] doesn't exist so you need SUMPRODUCT to count with multiple conditions....(or an array formula)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you expect to get 48 as the average for Apple?

Two possible ways.....

An array formula with AVERAGE

`=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A10="Apple",IF(B2:B10<>"",B2:B10)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

....or use SUMIF/SUMPRODUCT

`=SUMIF(A2:A10,"Apple",B2:B10)/SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10="Apple")*(B2:B10<>""))`

Comment: Off-topic alert! - I understand there were 5 completely new functions in Excel 2007, which were IFERROR, AVERAGEIF, AVERAGEIFS, COUNTIFS and SUMIFS - a whole group of others that were previously Analysis ToolPak add-in functions in Excel 2003 (like NETWORKDAYS and WEEKNUM, for example) became "inbuilt" function in 2007